# Building project with CUDA failed, Windows 7 Professional Visual Studio 2013 ultimate

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

I am trying to write OpenCV program with CUDA functionality, but my machine has no NVidia graphic card. So I succeeded compiling it,but couldn't run it. Ok, I understand that. But when I try to run it on a machine which has correctly configured OpenCV (other projects,but without CUDA functionality,were working just fine) and CUDA support I get this error:

[image]

Any solutions?

Comment: Probably, your target machine has an OpenCV built with CUDA disabled.

Comment: Ok, thanks. How can I  enable it?

Comment: You need to find another build (with CUDA enabled) of to build it yourself from source code.

Comment: Ok,does that involves CMakeLists.txt ?

Comment: Yes. [RTFM](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html) ;)